# Hibernate/JPA persist mapping OneToOne with sequence generator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 entities joined using a `@OneToOne` relation like this :

```
public class FirstEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FIRST_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_FIRST")
    private Long ID;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "first", targetEntity = SecondEntity.class,  cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private SecondEntity second;
}
```

And the other entity like that :

```
public class SecondEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SECOND_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_SECOND")
    private Long ID;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = firstEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "H_FIRST_FK")
    private FirstEntity first;
}
```

But when I want to add a new first entity and link the second one (**already existing**) to it I have a few issues.

```
    FirstEntity firstEntity = mapper.toEntity(firstDto);
    if(firstDto.getSecond() != null) {
        firstEntity.getSecond().setFirst(first);
    }

    firstRepository.save(firstEntity);
```

**Issue:** With this code I got a "*Detach Entity*" error, probably because Hibernate can't set the id of the first entity as it is a sql generator.

With this code :

```
    FirstEntity firstEntity = mapper.toEntity(firstDto);
    firstRepository.save(firstEntity);
    if(firstDto.getSecond() != null) {
        firstEntity.getSecond().setFirst(first);
    }
```

**Issue:** Nothing is saved for the `secondEntity` and the mapping isn't set..

For the moment the only thing that seems to be working is this:

```
    FirstEntity firstEntity = mapper.toEntity(firstDto);
    firstRepository.save(firstEntity);
    if(firstDto.getSecond() != null) {
        firstEntity.getSecond().setFirst(first);
    }
    firstRepository.save(firstEntity);
```

Is there a way to tell hibernate to :

- get the next sequence
- save the first
- merge the second with id of the first for the fk
  In one instruction instead of doing 2 saves manually?

All of that without having to double save ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i assume the SecondEntity already has an @Id field set.

As you already have the right cascade option: `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE`, i would simply replace the save with a merge in the first example:

```
FirstEntity firstEntity = mapper.toEntity(firstDto);
if(firstDto.getSecond() != null) {
    firstEntity.getSecond().setFirst(first);
}

firstRepository.merge(firstEntity);
```

This will persist the new FirstEntity instance and then merge the SecondEntity.

Just remember that if you want to perform any operations on the first entity after the merge you would have to work on a new instance:

```
FirstEntity mergedFirstEntity = firstRepository.merge(firstEntity);
// operations on mergedFirstEntity from now on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have never think about something as simple as that :o